# git get rid of a single post on a merged branch

Tags: git

[image]

How do I get rid of the commit "edit post".  I have tried to rebase -i at the sha for "update content" and the commit immediately prior to it. This always results in `fatal: invalid upstream '<sha>'`

It's not fundamentally important, but it was early in the history and it's a single line change. I can easily drop the commit and lose the change and redo it. Just dropping the commit shouldn't cause any problem.

(zsh makes me use the single quotes...)

Comment: If you're being told its an invalid upstream, something is wrong with your commit ID. Try `git log --graph --decorate --oneline` to get the commit IDs instead. In general it's best not to mess with merged commits. `git revert` would be more appropriate.

Comment: I have the valid commit id. Could the problem be that the local branch tracks a remote branch? Is there a different way I could refer to the commit?  I tried the revert of the offending (?) commit but the revision adds a new commit above HEAD. Is there a way to just DROP the commit?

Comment: Branch tracking would have no effect. We would need to see the relevant parts of `git log --graph --decorate --oneline` and your actual git commands to help.

Comment: This makes no sense. The commit "edit post" is the only commit on that branch. If you deleted it there would be nothing to merge. You are asking to delete the whole branch including the merge commit. So is that what you want? If so do you want the effect of the branch erased from all later commits? Or do you mean you wish you had done this directly on the main branch, and if so, why on earth do you wish that?

Answer (score 0):

**Notice:** I don't recommend editing history, *especially* if these commits have been pushed to any sort of shared repo.  A much cleaner solution is to do as Schwern suggests and `git revert` the commit.  That being said...

1. Check out the most recent commit on the branch you are rebasing (ex: if there are 3 commits above "update posts" in your screenshot, checkout the top-most commit).
2. `git rebase -i abcde` where abcde is replaced by "update content"'s ref.
3. Delete the rebase line for "edit post".
4. Save your commit.

Afterwards, you will have a newly generated hash for each commit after "update post".  You have basically rewritten your repository's history (hence my initial notice).  "edit post" and "update posts" commits will both be absent from this branch, though, as you requested.

Comment: I can get away with editing history. I am the only contributor. I can get mad at myself, but usually for different reasons than this.  First, the commit I want to get rid of is "edit post". Note that it is on a merged branch. I could drop it or squash it. Doesn't matter.

Answer (score -3):

I think the history is too complicated to fix. I am stuck with this one.  If the commits are in a straight line on a branch with no merges, I can squash them.

For the future, I will create a branch to do some of these greebly little fixes and then do a squash merge of the whole branch before pushing.

I got into this using Render for a static site generator, so I was pushing lots of little changes. But, I can test the SSG locally and not push to deploy until ready.

And I can do it on a different branch...

so, better workflow will prevent these little nits...

Thanks for suggestions.